# Is it possible to do arithmetic in Object keys?

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have an object where the keys are arbitrary values:

```
{
  1300: 'banana',
  267000: 'cheese',
  4000000: 'goat'
}
```

In some cases it would be clearer to others if I do some math, eg:

```
12 * 1000 * 1000: 'horse',
```

**Is doing maths in keys possible in JavaScript?**

I have tried:

```
(12 * 1000 * 1000): 'horse',
```

But it's a syntax error.

Comment: The name has to be a literal. You can assign the name dynamically later though: `obj[(12 * 1000 * 1000)] = 'horse'`

Comment: @haim770: you mean "had to be a literal"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your browser supports ES6, then you can use "computed keys".  The syntax is *close* to what you tried.  If you use `[]`, it should work:

```
{
    [12 * 1000 * 1000]: 'horse'
}
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

[Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility): Chrome, Firefox 34+, Safari 7.1+

Comment: watch for rounding errors on math here: the code shown is fine, but different browsers alias floats differently.

Comment: This is multiplication though, so there would be no issues with rounding errors. If division was used, then possibly? Right?

Answer (score 4):

When initializing an object, <s>you cannot use math to define keys</s>. You could however use the longer notation:

```
obj[(12 * 1000 * 1000)] = 'horse';
```

EDIT: Apparently it does look like you can use computed notation in ES6 as noted above.

```
var obj = {
  1300: 'banana',
  267000: 'cheese',
  4000000: 'goat',
  [12 * 1000 * 1000]: 'horse'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure. If you're using ES6 you can use the following notation. It's called [Computed Property Names](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-object-literal-features-in-depth#computed-property-names)

```
{
  1300: 'banana',
  267000: 'cheese',
  4000000: 'goat',
  [12 * 1000 * 1000]: 'horse'
}
```